# how to make a js textarea draggable

Tags: html, textarea

I have a textarea generated with the bellow js code, I also have a button that creates additional text areas when clicked, I NEED to make each text area draggable, Ussually because the "id" is "myForm" it should become draggable using jquery $('#myForm') but it does not work, I have try all forms but it does not work. I also have check similar questions but not luck... I will appreciate if some one can help me out. in the folder I have the Html, The css and all jquery libraries working Ok.
I check with the alert box.

Note: all I need is a textarea with a button to add as many additional text areas and this areas to be draggable, the code to generate this text areas can be any code. In case there is a easier way to accomplish the same thing... Thank you in advance.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("FORM");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myForm");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made for you kindly however dosn't work in this editor

```js
 var new_offset = {top:30, left:40};
 var new_width = 200;
 var new_height = 150;
 var newElement$ = $('<div><textarea id="textarea"></textarea></div>')
                                    .width(new_width)
            .height(new_height)
                                    .draggable({
                                        cancel: "text",
                                        start: function (){
                                            $('#textarea').focus();
                                         },
                                        stop: function (){
                                            $('#textarea').focus();
                                         } 
                                     })
                                    .resizable()
         .css({
           'position'         : 'absolute',
           'background-color'  : 'gray',
           'border-color'      : 'black',
           'border-width'      : '1px',
           'border-style'     : 'solid'
             })
          .offset(new_offset)
                   .appendTo('body');
```

```css
textarea {
    height:100%;
    background-color:whit;
    width:100%;
    resize:none; border:none;
    padding:0px; margin:0px;
    
}
div { padding:0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: The above code works BUT it keeps the additional textareas dragging along with the first textarea. How can each textarea be draggable on its own?

Comment: Thank You DarticCode, a better solution will be to get the code dynamicly create a new id to each new text area that is generated, Other ways its like no point on having to go inside the html file and do this manually... I do apreciate your help tho. Thank you.

Comment: I am new here to, Maybe you don't get credit because your answer was not complete and the question is not closed.

Comment: Sure I been trying all day long, Thanks in advance for your efforts.!

Comment: Finished look just needs jquery ui and jquery but it works!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is [HTML5 Drag and Drop](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) what you are looking for?

All you need to do is define `draggable=true` in your element and code the relevant `ondragstart` and `ondragend` logic. This works with both vanilla JS and frameworks like React.

Comment: What you telling me is to create a draggable area where other elements can be dragged into... what I have is a textarea and a button to add additional textareas... now I need to make this textareas draggable, CodeArtic try to help me but the code he give me draggs all text areas to the same place, I need to be able to drag each text area individually. Thanks

Comment: What I meant was that when you create the text area in `myFunction()` you can add the `draggable=true` attribute to it and specify the relevant `ondragstart` and `ondragend` logic for those relevant areas.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked it and piggy tailed to a span element this way the span element is easy to make draggable with jquery, The textarea is not draggable but it has to follow the span element THUS is draggable.

The span element has the class= "drag",then I used the jquery `$('.drag').draggable`  and that made the whole trick. Dirty code BUT it works 100% the way I needed.